# No Module error when running pytest for flask

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am trying to use pytest to test a flask app and failing at instantiating the app. I am getting the following error when running `pytest tests/`. The `flask --app main run` works fine.

```html
ImportError while importing test module '****/tests/test_eventlist.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_eventlist.py:2: in <module>
    from app import create_app
app/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from flask import Flask
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Here is my project structure.
[image]

Here is the code for test_eventlist.py file and my main.py

```html
import pytest
from app import create_app


@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.update({
        "TESTING": True,
    })
    yield app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


def test_eventlist_post(client):
    response = client.post("/", data={"filename": "sample1.txt",
                           "from": "2000-01-01T17:25:49Z", "to": "2000-01-10T16:55:01Z"})
    assert len(response) == 5
```

```html
from flask import Flask
from app import create_app

app = create_app()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please put the entire error message, including the stack trace if there is one, in your question. - Where is `create_app()` defined?  Without knowing the answer to these questions, I assume that the problem is that you are attempting to import from the `app` module in both cases, but in the case of the test file, that module is one level up in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Apologies, updated the error. @CryptoFool